# How to delete the 'triangle' on an arrow using the Vaucanson-g package

Tags: pstricks, arrows

I'm using the `vaucanson-g` package and I have the following now:

```
\MediumPicture\VCDraw{

\begin{VCPicture}{(5,-0)(3,-3)}  

\ChgEdgeNodeSep{6}

\StateVar[v]{(0,-5)}{A}

\StateVar[w]{(4,-2)}{B}

\StateVar[u]{(8,-5)}{C}

\LoopNW{B}{ }  

\EdgeL{B}{C}{ } 

\EdgeR{B}{A}{ } 

\end{VCPicture} }
```

However, I do not want the 'triangles' on the arrows; I want to delete them so I have the line only. To be very precise: if `->` symbolizes an arrow, I do not want the `>` at the end of the arrow, that is, I only want a *line* `-`. So I basically want to get rid of the `>` symbols in each of my arrows.

How do I get this done? It should be fairly easy I guess, but I've been searching for half an hour in the `vaucanson-g` manual but I still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\renewcommand{\EdgeArrowStyle}{-}
\renewcommand{\EdgeRevArrowStyle}{-}
```

to remove the arrow heads. Here's your code snippet in a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{vaucanson-g}% http://ctan.org/pkg/vaucanson-g
\renewcommand{\EdgeArrowStyle}{-}% Originally defined as ->
%\renewcommand{\EdgeRevArrowStyle}{-}% Originally defined as <-
\begin{document}

\MediumPicture\VCDraw{
  \begin{VCPicture}{(5,-0)(3,-3)}  
    \ChgEdgeNodeSep{6}
    \StateVar[v]{(0,-5)}{A}
    \StateVar[w]{(4,-2)}{B}
    \StateVar[u]{(8,-5)}{C}
    \LoopNW{B}{ }  
    \EdgeL{B}{C}{ } 
    \EdgeR{B}{A}{ } 
  \end{VCPicture}
}

\end{document}
```